# I'm getting an error when using spawn to run python in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, python, child-process, stderr, spawn

I am running the pyhyon script in javascipt, but I am getting an error.

Javascript code:

```
  const { spawn } = require("child_process");

  const python = spawn(
    "C:/Users/Murat/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe",
    ["../pythonScript/main.py"]
  );

  python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("It worked");        
  });

  python.stderr.on("data", (data) => {      
      console.error("stderr: ", data.toString());       
  });
```

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("Breast.csv")
print(dataset.shape)
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPbqu.png)

Comment: It looks like python cannot locate the .csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv file you're trying to access either doesn't exist or your current working  directory is not set correctly. Try putting a `chdir("Path to folder with Breast.csv");`